# How to navigate to a different page depending on who is logged in

Tags: java, jsp

I have a java web app which has an `Admin` role and `User` role. On a page which can be accessed by both roles, I want a home navigation button which when clicked takes them back to the home page. For the Admin this is admin.jsp and for the user this is home.jsp. I have tried the following in the navigation bar on the events page,

```
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="<%
                    if (session.getAttribute("role").equals("Admin")){
                        response.sendRedirect("admin.jsp");
                    } else{
                        response.sendRedirect("home.jsp");
                    }
                %>">Home</a>
            </li>
```

I am having an issue where when I am on the home page for a user and click on the events navigation link, it takes me back to the home.jsp page rather than the events.jsp page.

This is the code for the event navigation link on the user home page

```
             <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/events">Events <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
```

I am relatively new to writing JSP and can't figure out what is happening, I expected it would check if the role of the logged in person was Admin or user when I clicked on the home link on the events page, but it seems to be doing something when I click on the events link on the previous page.

Could some possibly explain what is happening and how I can resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.sendRedirect(...)` is telling your browser to change the page to `...`. So as soon as you navigate to the Events page as `admin`, the `.sendRedirect("admin.jsp")` does as you command, and sends you to `admin.jsp`. Rather than doing that, simply output the URL that the anchor tag should navigate to: `out.println("admin.jsp")` or `home.jsp`